# CURL - get Retrieve all email from Google API

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-email-audit-api

I'm using cURL to get all email from user via Google API. Following https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#retrieving_all_email_monitors_of_a_source_user.

According this tutorial, the server return '201 Created' status code to successful. But, my result return '200 OK' code.

Here is code Authorization

```
$data = array(
'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',  
'Email' => 'myEmail',  
'Passwd' => 'myPassword',  

'source'=>'PHP-cUrl-Example',  
'service'=>'apps');  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

And here is code to Retrieving all email monitors of a source user

```
preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
$auth = $matches[1];

$header = array('Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.trim($auth),
    );
$url_email ="https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/monitor/mydomain/username";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_email); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = simplexml_load_string($response);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Help me pls ?

Comment: What is the result when you retrieve all email monitors? Is the one you created there?

Comment: @EmilyLam: return AtomPub feed with no entry element for all email monitors

Answer (score 0):

The API allows you to [request the status of a single export request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#retrieving_the_export_status_of_a_mailbox) with a URL of:

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/export/{domain name}/{source user name}/{mailbox requestId}

or of [all requests across the domain](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#retrieving_all_mailbox_status_requests) with a request of:

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/export/{domain name}?fromDate={fromDate}

there is no operation to retrieve the status of all requests for a given user like you are trying to do.

I suggest you confirm you've successfully created an audit request by using [GAM](http://ditoweb.com/dito-gam) to [create the request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/ExamplesAccountAuditing#Request_an_Export_of_a_User%27s_Mailbox). GAM will show you the request ID on success. Then you can try getting the results of the single request with your code.

Comment: I mean that the response requests no return data although I authenticated successful.

Comment: can you clarify if you're having issues with the create or the get?